# qrc_resource.cpp error while compiling in debug mode

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qmake

I am trying to compile my Qt application but getting error

```
:-1: error: [debug/qrc_cinemasresource.cpp] Error 1
```

I tried checking all the resource but noting looks missed

Answer (score 0):

The reason of this error could be found in "Compile Output" tab.

Please check this [similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786946/qt-doesnt-seem-to-process-resource-file). It helped to solve my issue.

In my case the problem was in the file that was listed in qrc-file, but didn't exist physically.